# CSS not loading until after manually refreshing

Tags: css

I'm having an issue where on the first load of a page the styling isn't applied.

On the login and register pages of a web app I am working on the styling isn't applied until I manually refresh. This doesn't happen on any other page of my app, just the login and register screens. You may be able to experience the issue here: https://app.pulseproduct.com/register/personal

There is a before and after refreshing screenshot here:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

This issue is across Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

Comment: I loaded your page on Chrome and Safari. Both times the css came in right.

Comment: yes it work's on mine to

Comment: Yes It is working on mine to

Answer (score 0):

i checked it for you and i found it's works fine in my end
clear your browser cash and try or 
you can use incognito Mode on Chrome or Private Mode in FireFox
i hope your problem is fix and this would help you.

[image: it's load with css correctly]